# Is there any way to edit VS 10 projects in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, compatibility

I worked for a friend's project in VS 2008.
Now I upgraded it to 2010 version, I wanna send it back to my friend so he should be able to use it.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no. If you want to allow using vs10 and vs2008 at the same time, you need to use separate project files.

Answer (score 5):

Well, between VS2005 and VS2008, this little trick used to work - not sure if it still does between VS2008 and VS2010 though (haven't had the time to test it myself).

The first line in the solution file (`YourProject.sln`) contains the version info which VS created the file. If it's "too high", a downlevel VS won't open it.

First of all, **MAKE A BACKUP** !

Basically just change that first line in your solution file to be

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
```

Version 10.00 is VS2008 - Version 9.00 was VS2005.

Now try to open your solution in VS2008 - it might just work (no guarantees, though!!).

Marc

Comment: There a few several files that caused problems, such as DBML files.

Comment: OK, thanks for the feedback - I went back and forth between VS2008 and VS2005 without any trouble, but haven't tried with VS2010 / VS2008 yet.

Answer (score 2):

If all you've done is edit the source files, the best approach is probably to send those back and have your friend re-integrate them into his vs2008 project.

If you've added files, you may still be able to get them integrated okay. What will cause trouble is if there are binary files that VS2008 doesn't know about.

I'm not aware of any tools that will automatically convert *projects* back into vs2008 so the re-integration may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

why aren't you using windiff between the 2008 sln file and the 2010 sln and see how it was before and what has been changed. It should with small modifications.

Answer (score 0):

No, because VS stored version number in solution file.

You need two different solution file. Each for VS version. But I think, this isn't good solution. Better is you convince your friend to upgrade, too.

Comment: Better for all would be for vs2010 person to downgrade to the supported and well-tested vs2008 version. Unless you want to spend your life beta-testing MS' products :-)

Comment: We are beta testers. We using gmail (still in beta), bing, serverfault, windows7 and many others product. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes vs2008 can work with vs2010 project files just fine, the problem is with the solution file for some reason. vs2008 refuses to open vs2010 solutions and vs2010 refuses to open vs2008, so you have to make one for each.

After you have run the upgrade wizard in vs2010, close the solution. Now make a copy of it so that you have two and name the new one with a "08" suffix or something. Open that solution file in a text editor and change "11" to "10" on the first line.

Voila! Now you have one solution that will work for vs2008 and one for vs2010 and they are sharing the same projects.