# How can I use the same solution file in VS 2008 and VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I have recently installed VS 2008. Now I want to open my VS2010 project's solution (sln) file in VS 2008. How can I do it?

Comment: I think your bigger problem would be to open the solution underlying projects...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to edit VS 10 projects in VS 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963417/is-there-any-way-to-edit-vs-10-projects-in-vs-2008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot share the same solution file between 2008 and 2010. Each VS version expects its own .sln file version. You can downgrade 2010 .sln manually by opening it in Notepad and rewritting.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.0 
# Visual Studio 2010
```

To

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.0 
# Visual Studio 2008
```

It works only for solutions which doesn't use any new features from VS 2010 and once you try open the file again in VS 2010 it will have to upgrade it.

The best way is using separate .sln file for VS 2008 and 2010

Answer (score 4):

Rename VS2010 solution file to `MySolution.VS2010.sln` and using VS2008 create a new solution file name `MySolution.VS2008.sln` which then you may use them side by side. We're currently using a similar solution for our projects.

If're using a complementary tool like ReSharper, it would be best to use separate directories for solution files. You can see ELMAH source code for that (the 'ELMAH\src\Solutions' folder). Go to the link and inspect the left pane for separate solution folders with .sln files in it: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/#svn%2Ftags%2FREL-1.2%2Fsrc%2FSolutions